# What does this C++ constructor in the initialization list mean?

Tags: c++, constructor

I found this C++ constructor that uses an initialization list I don't understand what this convention is. I do know this initialization list can be use to instantiate a member of a instance with a param, but I've never seen a class constructor called from a list.

```
// G inherits from H
class GBackend : public HBackend {...}

// Constructor for G
// What is this HBackend constructor doing?
GBackend::GBackend(const BackendOptions& options) : HBackend(options), g_options(options) {...}
```

Comment: You mean you understand the initialization of the member `g_options`, but not the initialization of the base class `HBackend`?

Comment: It's like calling the `super` constructor in Java; it delegates to the parent class' constructor to initialize the fields declared there.

Comment: @JaMiT Yes. I've seen other C++ code that uses initialization lists to set a field within the instance, but I've never seen another constructor called.

Comment: @knowads Cool. That's an important detail when choosing which question to redirect this to. (It looks like the canonical question for "What is this weird colon-member syntax" covers only member initialization.)